# Move row up and down in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Consider a QTableWidget and two buttons "move up" and "move down". Clicking on move up, the current row should move up one row, analogously for "move down".

What's the easiest way to implement the corresponding move up and move down functions? or Is it possible to update this snippet code to pyqt5 which does the same task in pyqt4!

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class mtable(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)


        self.move_up = QtGui.QAction("Move_Up", self)
        self.connect(self.move_up, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.moveUp)

        self.move_down = QtGui.QAction("Move_Down",self)
        self.connect(self.move_down, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.moveDown)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.move_up)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.move_down)


        ##Init Table
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(4,3)
        for i in range(0,4):
            for j in range(0,4):
                self.table.setItem(i,j,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("a_"+str(i)+str(j)))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

    def moveDown(self):
        row = self.table.currentRow()
        column = self.table.currentColumn();
        if row < self.table.rowCount()-1:
            self.table.insertRow(row+2)
            for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
               self.table.setItem(row+2,i,self.table.takeItem(row,i))
               self.table.setCurrentCell(row+2,column)
            self.table.removeRow(row)        


    def moveUp(self):    
        row = self.table.currentRow()
        column = self.table.currentColumn();
        if row > 0:
            self.table.insertRow(row-1)
            for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
               self.table.setItem(row-1,i,self.table.takeItem(row+1,i))
               self.table.setCurrentCell(row-1,column)
            self.table.removeRow(row+1)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tb = mtable()
    tb.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do to convert to PyQt5 is change the imports and modules from QtGui to QtWidgets and the syntax for the signal-slot connection.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class mtable(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.move_up = QtWidgets.QAction("Move_Up", self)
        self.move_up.triggered.connect(self.moveUp)

        self.move_down = QtWidgets.QAction("Move_Down",self)
        self.move_down.triggered.connect(self.moveDown)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.move_up)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.move_down)

        ##Init Table
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4,3)
        for i in range(0,4):
            for j in range(0,4):
                self.table.setItem(i,j,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("a_"+str(i)+str(j)))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
```

The rest of the class should be the same, just one more edit for QApplication.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tb = mtable()
    tb.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```